# Tinymce Angular 2 ResponsiveFileManager

Tags: angular, tinymce, responsive-filemanager

I had to get Tinymce working in an Angular 4 project with the responsivefilemanager plugin. I could not find the detailed steps anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that got it working for me.

Step 1

```
npm install --save angular2-tinymce
```

Step 2 
In the assets folder->tinymce I copied the entire tinmce folder e.g. plugins, skins, themes etc

Step 3
Add the following to the angular-cli.json scripts section

```
"./assets/tinymce/plugins/responsivefilemanager/plugin.js"
```

Step 4
In the app.module.ts add the following

```
import { TinymceModule } from 'angular2-tinymce';
```

Step 5
I updated TinymceOptions to include extra fields for responsivefilemanager

```
external_filemanager_path?: string;
filemanager_title?: string;
filemanager_crossdomain?: boolean;
```

Step 6
@NgModule -> imports section add the following

```
TinymceModule.withConfig({
  plugins: ['responsivefilemanager'],
  toolbar: 'responsivefilemanager',
  menubar: false,
  external_filemanager_path: environment.contentServer,
  filemanager_title: 'My Content Server',
  filemanager_crossdomain: true
})
```

Step 7
Add to html page

```
<app-tinymce [(ngModel)]='ImageIcon'></app-tinymce>
```